# Emulating a low-end server

Tags: virtual-machine, emulation

I'm trying to figure out the cheapest possible hardware required for my servers.

The software is written in c++ and is highly efficient, the most computationally intensive thing it has to do is creating plain TAR files on the fly so the requirements are probably very low.. however, I still want to test this out since I'd be getting a whole bunch of these cheapo servers.

Is there any VM software or something else that would allow me to emulate low CPU/disk performance?

Comment: VirtualBox supports CPU capping. You can also try disabling the CPU cache and getting a super slow PC.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I simulate a slow machine in a VM?](https://superuser.com/questions/297550/how-can-i-simulate-a-slow-machine-in-a-vm)

Answer (score 1):

With PCem you can emulate a Pentium 233 Mhz with an IDE drive - if it is responsive on that, it would run great on the cheapest and most overprovisioned of the VPS

Or you could run it on an older computer of yours

Comment: It works great on the oldest computer I have but it has an e8400 which downclocked  is still 4x more powerful than the atom/jaguar CPU's I'm considering :|