# A way to simulate slower pcs using my application

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, hyper-v

We are looking for a way to emulate a slow PC, using any virtualization technology. Our goal is to cap the network speed and simulate a CPU with fewer GHz.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://superuser.com/a/516414/304064) on how to limit CPU speed in VirtualBox

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I simulate a slow machine in a VM?](http://superuser.com/questions/297550/how-can-i-simulate-a-slow-machine-in-a-vm), [Limiting CPU speed in a virtual machine?](http://superuser.com/questions/265322/limiting-cpu-speed-in-a-virtual-machine/)